# kendo is not defined after upgrade springboot from 2.0 to 3.1

Tags: spring-mvc, kendo-ui

I just upgraded springboot from version 2.0 to 3.1 and java from version 8 to 17 and I got the problem that kendo is not being read

There shouldn't be any problems with his kendo because I didn't change anything in his kendo

Comment: Please provide more information like the error messages you got and the command you executed.